# How to draw a directed arc in Open Layers 3 with the "direction arrow" at the center of the arc?

Tags: javascript, geometry, trigonometry, openlayers-3

I am using [Open Layers 3](http://openlayers.org/) and SpringMeyer's [Arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) to draw a directed arc on a map between two points:

[OpenLayers 3 Arc with Arc.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxiX3.png)

[image: OpenLayers 3 Arc with Arc.js]

I am a bit embarrassed to admit I have worked on this problem for hours, but I can't figure out how to center the arrow at the apex (middle) of the arc. Instead of at the end point, I would like the arrow to be at the center of the arc.

Here is a working Codepen with my code: http://codepen.io/gracefulcode/pen/MwYQzY

Here is my code:

```
 function createArcBetweenPoints(pointA, pointB, layer) {
  var transformedA = pointA.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  var transformedB = pointB.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  var start = { x: transformedA.getCoordinates()[0], y: transformedA.getCoordinates()[1] };
  var end = { x: transformedB.getCoordinates()[0], y: transformedB.getCoordinates()[1] };
  var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start, end, {'name': ''});
  var line = generator.Arc(100,{offset:10});
  var coordinates = line.geometries[0].coords;
  var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
  var geom = lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var feature = new ol.Feature({
      'geometry': geom
    });

  //Adds an arrow
  var dx = end.x - start.x;
  var dy = end.y - start.y - 20;
  var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  var lineStyles = [
    // linestring
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: pointB,
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'resources/arrow.png',
        anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
        rotateWithView: false,
        rotation: -rotation
      })
    })
  ];

  feature.setStyle(lineStyles);

  return feature;
}
```

Comment: I created a simple "hack-y" solution: http://codepen.io/gracefulcode/pen/KpwoQg

By finding the center point of the arc by simply picking the "middle" of the coordinates array that is produced when creating the arc, I just attach that geometry to the arrow's style. However, if anyone is able to come up with a more mathematical, non-hack solution, I would be very interested!

Comment: You could find the middle point between start and end, i.e. [middle_of_x, middle_of_y] . Then, you can scan the array (all of it, or only its middle part)  and calculate for each coordinate its distance from the middle point you found before. The minimum distance is the point you need.